# Inequality about sums and products

Tags: inequality, radicals, fractions, products, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ be positive real numbers. Show that
$$\frac {1} {2^n \times \sqrt {x_1 \times x_2 \times ... \times x_n} } + \sum_ {k=1}^n \frac {x_k} {(x_1+1)(x_2+1)...(x_k+1)} \ge 1.$$
I tried to use AM-GM, but I didn't get to any result.

Comment: Shouldn't the $x_k$ on the denominator of the sum be $x_n$?

Comment: In my book, it is $x_k$, but I can't guarantee it is correct. Do you have any proof with $x_n$.

Comment: No, I was just wondering. Actually it makes sense, since otherwise the sum would be too small to yield something ≥1 when we sum the other term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n}x_i}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{x^k}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^k(1+x_i)}\geq1\Leftrightarrow\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n}x_i}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1+x_k}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^k(1+x_i)}\geq1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^k(1+x_i)}\Leftrightarrow$

$\Leftrightarrow\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n}x_i}\geq\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1+x_i)}$, which is just AM-GM

Comment: The last one shouldn't be $\iff$, it looks like $\Leftarrow$, but looks good otherwise +1.

Comment: @ Macavity$\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n}x_i}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1+x_k}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^k(1+x_i)}-1-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^k(1+x_i)}=\frac{1}{2^n\sqrt{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n}x_i}-\frac{1}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(1+x_i)}$